# How can I import a PGP public key into Keychain Access.app?

Tags: keychain, encryption

I have someone's PGP Public Key (.asc) and would like to import that into Keychain Access.app so that I can email them with my existing PKI certificates which I already use with Mail.app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to mix two different encryption schemes here: S/MIME and PGP. Mail.app supports S/MIME by default, so I guess that's what you're currently using. PGP support can be added by installing the Mail plugin that is part of the [GPG Suite](https://gpgtools.org). After you also generate a PGP key for yourself, you can use both S/MIME and PGP encryption. You can receive and decode both, and for each email you're sending, you can choose which one to use.

GPG Suite contains a separate GPG Keychain app for PGP keys.

Answer (score 2):

PGP and PKI are two somehow similar but differently working cryptographical schemes ([PGP/GPG vs. PKI](http://geminisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/tools/hope2008-pgp-vs-pki.pdf)). Keychain Access doesn't provide PGP support. Instead you have to download [GPG Suite 2015.08](https://gpgtools.org/) which contains its own GPGKeychain.app.

[Here](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/the-best-pgp-tutorial-for-mac-os-x-ever/) you will find a tutorial how to work with it.